# Unable to Create Hyperlink in Cell Text

Tags: c#, telerik

I am trying to embed hyperlink in worksheet cell text. But below block of code doesn't work for me. I am using telerik library here. What's wrong in below code?

```
using(var rowExporter = sheetExporter.CreateRowExporter())
{
    String policy = “<a href=https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/sample-terms-and-conditions-template/> Policy Terms</a>”;
    String showText = “For necessary info, Please refer “ +policy;
    Using var cellExporter = rowExporter.CreateCellExporter();
    cellExporter.SetValue(showText);
}
```

Comment: What library is that?

Comment: Telerik IWorkSheetExporter

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a syntax problem, I'm not an expert, but I could be wrong, but try using this code:

```
using(var rowExporter = sheetExporter.CreateRowExporter())
{
    string policy = "<a href=\"https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/sample-terms-and-conditions-template/\">Policy Terms</a>";
    string showText = "For necessary info, Please refer " + policy;
    using var cellExporter = rowExporter.CreateCellExporter();
    cellExporter.SetValue(showText);
}
```

I didn't change much, just small things, try and see if it works like this

Comment: No. It's not working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).